# Invariant Subspaces of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, invariant-subspace

Does there exist a nontrivial subspace of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ that is invariant under (horizontal) translation (i.e. any element of this subspace must also have its translates in the subspace)? I thought the answer is yes, but after trying examples such as the bounded functions of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ (which yields the trivial subspace of itself) and analytic functions of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ (which appears to yield the trivial zero subspace), I am not so sure.

Comment: Any translation invariant function is constant, so the only translation invariant compactly supported function (let alone subspace) is the zero function. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps my original phrasing was slightly misleading - I'm looking for a nontrivial subspace of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that if any element in this subspace is translated, then the result still remains in this subspace.

Comment: I dont get the question: Cant you just take a single $C_c^\infty$ function and then create the subspace by taking all possible translations of that single function?

Comment: I believe the issue with this construction is that $0$ is not in the subspace, and the sum of any two elements in the subspace is not necessarily a translate.

Comment: My thoughts are that there is no such subspace. I also thought of taking a non-trivial $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ function then creating a set by taking all the translations. Now this is not a vector space, so you then want to take it's span, but I suspect that that will give you $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$

Comment: If you can show the above then this will prove no such non-trivial subspace can exist.

Comment: @JackT. I don't think that you will get $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$ All sums are finite; to get $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ we would most probably need to use series.

Comment: You can consider the space $$X=\left\{\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) : \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0\right\}.$$ Being the kernel of a linear functional, it is a subspace of $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any nonzero $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$ Then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi'(x)\,dx=0$ and the same is valid for any rescaling and translation of $\psi,$ as well as for any finite sum of such.

Now let $X$ be the linear space generated by all translations and rescalings of $\psi'.$ Then, for all $\varphi\in X$ one has $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(x) \, dx = 0$ so $X$ is a nontrivial subspace of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$

**Easier**
Just take $X = \{ \varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R) \mid \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(x) \, dx = 0 \}.$

Comment: Nice. That's much easier than my answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea to consider analytic functions could work.

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ be a function which is nowhere real analytic (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic). Let
$$
g(x):=\exp(-\frac{1}{1-x^2}) ~ (x \in (-1,1)) \quad g(x)=0 ~ (|x|\ge 1).
$$
Then $g \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ and $g$ is real analytic in each $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1,1\}$. Set
$$
U= {\rm span} \{x\mapsto g(x+c): c \in \mathbb{R}\}.
$$
Each $h \in U$ is of the form
$$
h(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k g(x+c_k),
$$
hence the set of points where $h$ is not real analytic is finite. Now $gf \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})\setminus U$ since the set of points where $gf$ is not real analytic contains $(-1,1)$.